# Vk api python, отправка поста в открытую группу

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

**Данный код выдаёт следующий exception, на сколько я понимаю ошибка в передаваемых мною параметрах, буду рад любому совету, (Особенно касаемо правильное вариации метода post)**

```
import vk

my_app_id = 6923464
user_login = '_________' 

user_password = '_______________'

session = vk.AuthSession(scope='wall', app_id=my_app_id, user_login=user_login, user_password=user_password)

vk.api.access_token="195797facc4009b255areghrhtthththh"

api = vk.API(session)

api.wall.post(owner_id='-90444903',message="Просто 
текст...!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть [синтаксис запроса к VK API](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests):
*https*://api.vk.com/method/**METHOD_NAME**?**PARAMETERS**&access_token=**ACCESS_TOKEN**&v=**V**

> **V** (обязательно) — используемая версия API. Использование этого параметра применяет некоторые изменения в формате ответа различных методов. На текущий момент актуальная версия API — 5.92. Этот параметр следует передавать со всеми запросами.

Т.е. версию API обязательно передавать в каждом запросе. В Вашем же случае запрос будет выглядеть так:

```py
api.wall.post(owner_id='-90444903',message="Просто текст...!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!",v="5.92")
```

Но можно и поступить проще, дабы в каждом запросе явно не передавать параметр **v**:

```py
session = vk.AuthSession(scope='wall', app_id=my_app_id, user_login=user_login, user_password=user_password)

api = vk.API(session, v="5.92")
```

Далее можно вызывать методы API без указания **v** в каждом запросе (по умолчанию будет 5.92).

З.Ы. А зачем Вам **access_token**, если Вы используете `AuthSession`? Он там не нужен, насколько я знаю.

Answer (score 3):

Советую почитать ошибку, там пишет что необходима версия апи, добавь `v="5.92"` в запрос